# Need help solving proof involving equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prop: Let ~ be an equivalence relation on a set A, and a, b ∈ A. If a ~ b, then [a] = [b] and if a ≁ b, then [a] ∩ [b] = ∅.

What I understand so far: an equivalence relation has to have 3 properties: reflexive, symmetric, and transitivity. Both a and b are elements of the set A and the questions asking if a and b's cardinality are equal and if a is not an equivalence relation to b, then the intersection of there cardinality must be equal to the empty set.

However I don't quite understand how to write a proof for this proposition, an elementary proof would be absolutely amazing alongside some explanation.

Thank you for all the support math.StackExchange members!

Comment: It's not asking about cardinality.

Comment: that would explain my confusion as the cardinality of an element makes absolutely no sense.

I don't quite understand what the question is asking..

Comment: $[a]$ is the equivalence class of $a$ under the relation.

Comment: $[a]=\{ x \in A | x \sim a \}$ ... does that help?

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $[a]\cap[b] \neq \emptyset$. Then there is a $c \in [a]\cap[b]$. Then, by the definition of equivalence classes and intersection, $a\sim c \land c\sim b$. By the transitivity of equivalence relations, $a\sim b$: contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand that proof, I guess equivalence classes are confusing me a bit here.

Comment: Then you need to study the definitions of each of reflexive, symmetric, and transitive as properties of relations.  When you have an equivalence relation the set is divided into equivalence classes.  All the elements in a class are related and no elements that are in different classes are related.